# Overlay histogram with kernel density for different data sets on different x-scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel, histogram, overlay

I have two plots for different subsets of my data:

1. one kernel estimation plot for data > 0
2. one histogram (actually only one bin) for data == 0

which I would like to combine in one plot using ggplot2.

Problem is, that ggplot continues to draw the line of my kernel for the whole x axis.

```
values <- c(25.222222, 6.000000, 2.057143, 0.000000, 2.142857, 0.000000, 73.666667, 
            4.081081, 43.133333, 18.937500, 60.822222, 23.379310, 54.954412, 8.492308, 
            67.646250, 15.885000, 38.585859, 46.810606, 31.565152, 39.813889, 
            40.620000, 25.958000, 54.821429, 9.000000, 33.040476, 50.329670, 43.525641, 
            33.508696, 34.265385, 57.003544, 36.690434, 48.074074, 70.372222, 
            77.602564, 29.997436, 71.739683, 11.320000, 2.938776, 10.101562, 35.037956)

df <- data.frame(variable = "TH_part", value=values)

library(ggplot2)

p1.kernel <- ggplot(subset(df, value!=0), aes(x=value, y=..density.., color=variable)) +
  geom_density() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 200)) + theme_bw()

p1.kernel + 
  geom_histogram(data=subset(df, value==0), 
                 aes(x=value, y=..density.., fill=variable), 
                 breaks=seq(-10,200,by=10), alpha=0.4) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 200)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

kernel plot within limits:

[image: kernel plot within limits]

kernel plus histogram but outside limits:

[image: kernel plus histogram but outside limits]

How can I use different limits on my xaxis?

And besides, why are the diagrams no longer in relation?
If I look at this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, y=..density.., color=variable)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,200,by=10), fill="white") +
  geom_density() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 200)) + theme_bw()
```

then the bar/bin should be much smaller (since only a part at the beginning is 0).

Extra: using `stat_density(adjust = 0.5)` to control the kernel smoothing factor will give me a second kernel in the plot. How can I use a smaller smoothing factor in the overlayed plot above?

**EDIT:**

with help from GGamba I got this plot, with counts on y-axis:

[image: plot with counts on y-axis]

Here, the bin of the 0-entries is much smaller in relation to the density.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `trim` argument. From `?geom_density`:

> **trim**
>   This parameter only matters if you are displaying multiple densities in one plot. If FALSE, the default, each density is computed on the full range of the data. If TRUE, each density is computed over the range of that group: this typically means the estimated x values will not line-up, and hence you won't be able to stack density values.

And you can use the `adjust` argument just fine in `geom_density` also.

```r
values <- c(25.222222, 6.000000, 2.057143, 0.000000, 2.142857, 0.000000, 73.666667, 4.081081, 43.133333, 18.937500, 60.822222, 23.379310, 54.954412, 8.492308, 67.646250, 15.885000, 38.585859, 46.810606, 31.565152, 39.813889, 40.620000, 25.958000, 54.821429, 9.000000, 33.040476, 50.329670, 43.525641, 33.508696, 34.265385, 57.003544, 36.690434, 48.074074, 70.372222, 77.602564, 29.997436, 71.739683, 11.320000, 2.938776, 10.101562, 35.037956)

df <- data.frame(variable = "TH_part", value=values)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(subset(df, value!=0), aes(x=value, y=..density.., color=variable)) +
  geom_density(trim = TRUE, adjust = .5) + 
  geom_histogram(data=subset(df, value==0), 
                 aes(x=value, y=..density.., fill=variable), alpha=0.4, breaks=seq(-10,200,by=10)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 200)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot! But how does it happen that the bin of my 0-entries is this high? Should not the bar be much smaller than the density? (see my edit and plot above)